# proxyaddresses attribute not updating in GlobalAddressList

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I had an issue creating a user in our domain, things are on track now, except one thing: I had to manually add the name@domain.local entry with the Exchangemgmgt console. Most users don't have the recent entry in their copy of the GlobalAddressList in outlook, so mails send internally are failing.
Other user, who see the new entry have no issues whatsoever.

I tried forcing an update via powershell "get-globaladdresslist | update-globaladdresslist" and manually re-requesting the addressbook in outlook, but this didn't do the trick.

What can I do so everyone gets the info?

Comment: If you setup a new Office client (a new profile) did you checked if the offline adressbook is downloaded correctly?

Comment: No, never checked this (never before had a reason to), how can I do that?

Comment: The first to always check is whether email works through OWA. That is live information. If that doesn't work, then the issue is more serious. 

Manually adding the internal email address shouldn't be required, so you need to look at whether the server is correctly configured. As this is an SBS server you need to run the fix my network wizard to begin with. Was the server setup with the wizards? Are you creating the users with the wizards?

Comment: It took a while (the weekend), but now Outlook is synchronizing the address book on each client with the correct information.